# Make Chatter Profile Photo available externally?

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, chatter, force.com-sites

I'm working on making some email templates, made of various visualforce components. One of these includes some information about a user they'll be interacting with. Additionally, this component includes the users profile image. We're using the image uploaded to their chatter profile, since most users already have images stored here.

Here's the problem: the chatter profile picture isn't accessible when not logged in, which the viewer never will be, since they're looking at the image in an email.

We've avoided this for the other images by using documents, and checking the "available externally" field for these records.

We've discussed these options:

1. Rest API/Public Site url - Takes an id parameter (a user id) and provides the profile picture for that user. Seems like a solid solution, but still has to deal with logged in/out contexts, and exposes user ids/document ids to all our clients, which feels like a vulnerability. Also feels like a lot of work to get a content delivery network up, when I could use other features instead, which puts the burden of security onto Salesforce & not the public site.
2. <strike>Base64 Images</strike>  - If this was a web page, this would be the ideal solution, but it seems some email clients still don't support base64 images, making this a poor solution.
3. <strike>Upload images to documents - Would require additional fields or settings to track the images per user & requires double upload to get the image in both places. Would prefer to avoid this, unless done via automation to avoid some of the duplication (which might be tough since updating the images doesn't seem to cause triggers to fire).</strike>  Looks like documents "Available Externally" Setting only applies to HTML email templates, making this worthless for my visualforce template. Will be looking into using Chatter files instead.
4. <strike>Host the images on another domain</strike> - feels brittle, if anything needs to be updated, or the domain experiences issues, suddenly our emails are missing their images.
5. <strike>Obtain the image via the REST API's Photo Object, which includes a `fullEmailPhotoUrl` field,</strike> however, this image url expires after 30 days, which isn't a dealbreaker, but is enough of a downside for me to look for another solution.

Are there any other alternatives to the approaches above? Has anyone successfully implemented an solution to this issue?

Comment: Would using a (symmetrically) encrypted, salted version of the User Id as an access token on a publicly accessible, unauthenticated REST API address the concerns for option (1)? I've applied that type of approach in the past in a different context.

Comment: Would certainly help! I could also use the document id instead of a user id too. Ill keep it in mind, but I think using chatter files delivered via `ContentDistribution`'s created by a batch job running on users with profile pictures is my solution to this problem. Feels like a safer alternative & is supported out of the box (kind of).

Comment: That makes sense - is there a possible race condition between the batch process and the email sending job, though?

Comment: Job runs at midnight & checks for users with a profile pic (`IsProfilePhotoActive`) & either a changed image, or a user without a saved id, then creates a file, then a content delivery record, then updates the user records with those ids when it finishes. The email send is in a separate context, & is designed to use the default picture if no picture is ready for a given user, otherwise it uses the image provided by the delivery record's id. I've seen references to this in other questions but never a full code sample, I hope to deliver soon!

Comment: This project got pushed to the backburner, so I don't have anything complete to share - if anyone finds this question via search & needs an answer, ping me in comments & I can provide more info.